# Logical deduction without completeness theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I am just learning about deduction and I have to solve the following exercises

Let $\Sigma$ be a consistent set of propositions. Which of the following statements are necessarily true? Justify your answer

1. If $\Sigma\vdash (\phi \lor \psi)$ then $\Sigma\vdash \phi$ or $\Sigma \vdash \psi$.
2. If $\Sigma\vdash (\phi\iff \psi)$ then $\Sigma\vdash \phi$ or $\Sigma\vdash \psi$.
3. If $\Sigma\vdash \phi$ then $\Sigma \not\vdash \neg \phi.$

My attempt:

4. False. Counterexample, $\Sigma=\{\phi\lor \psi\}$. Clearly $\Sigma\vdash (\phi\lor \psi)$ but neither $\Sigma\vdash\phi$ nor $\Sigma\vdash \psi$.
5. Solved by @Daniel Schepler at comments
6. Follows directly from that $\Sigma$ is consistent.

Comment: $3.$ is true since a consistent theory cannot derive a statement and also its negation. $2.$ is false since both statements might be false and the theory can be able to derive that. I do not understand your argument for $1.$ Why did you use "cannot derive" , if in the question we have "can derive" ?

Comment: @Peter In 1 I use cannot derive because I think that neither $\{\phi\lor \psi\} \not\vdash \phi$ nor $\{\phi\lor \psi\} \not\vdash \psi$, but if I'm wrong, I'll have to check this further.

Comment: @Peter Yeah .. I was just thinking about that.  I guess my question is how $\vdash$ is defined/used in this question.  Is it simply membership of $\Gamma$? (i.e. are we talking about a theory?) ... or are we to comtemplate some set of statement that is semantically logically consistent, but there might still be a some (unsound) derivational system that is able to derive contradictions or whatever?

Comment: @Haus That the theory only contains the mentioned proposition is a good approach. But to refute the implication, you have to show that it can neither derive the first nor the second proposition. So, if you would have used the same argument (with the "neither") but with "can derive" in both cases, I would agree the argument.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, then am I wrong in saying that neither $\{\phi \lor \psi \}\not\vdash \phi$ nor $\{\phi \lor \psi \}\not\vdash \psi$?

Comment: This is a double negation and means that the proposition in the brackets can derive both propositions. You can say "both ...", then it is correct again.

Comment: Ahhh now I understand, sorry, my English is not good. For item 2 and 3, in particular item 2, is there any method to prove it? I understand what you mention about its falsehood, but I need to prove it.

Comment: Seems that you can use your argument for $1$. also for $2$. $3.$ is easy : the implication is only false if the assumption is true and the implicated proposition is false. That means $\phi$ can be derived , but $not-\phi$ as well. This is impossible since the theory is consistent.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will try it.

Comment: For (2), the idea is that for all you know $\phi$ and $\psi$ could both be false.  For example, a bit more formally, try $\phi = \psi = p$ where $p$ is an atomic proposition variable, $\Sigma = \{ \}$; and then $\Sigma \vdash (\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ because $p \leftrightarrow p$ is a tautology, but $\Sigma \not\vdash \phi$ because you can take a model where $p$ is assigned to be false, and similarly $\Sigma \not\vdash \psi$.

Comment: When you put $\Sigma=\{ \}$ you don't mean that $\Sigma$ is the empty set, right? Is just a models such that $p$ is assigned to be false.